# how to convert Dimension values to string or int

Tags: java, swing

Is there a method to convert type Dimension to String so that it could be displayed in a JTextField? Or could you suggest any other possible way to display dimension, please?

Comment: Well if you call method toString() it will return a string representation of the values of this Dimension object's height and width fields.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the asker does not appear to have tried to solve it himself.

Comment: yes it did not worked

Comment: It depends.  What is it you want to display.  Using `Dimension#toString` may not result in a suitable format for output, whereas `dim.width + "x" + dim.height` may...

Comment: @SeekingAlpha `java.awt.Dimension[width=100,height=100]` - not sure this is suitable for display purpose, but since the OP has failed to provide information about the formatting...who knows...

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok dim.width + "x" + dim.height worked

Comment: i was trying to display it for JTextField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Suggest any possible way to display dimension"*

The first reality to accept is, not everything is already done for you.  This means, at some point in time, you're going to have to roll up your sleeves and do it yourself.  Knowing when to do this comes from experience and lots of research.

You've provided absolutely no context to what it is you are trying to achieve...

You could:

- Use two `JSpinners` one representing the `width` and one representing the `height`.  This has the benifit of providing a means by which the values can be edited.
- Create a `String` based on the `width` and `height` of `Dimension`, for example `dim.width + "x" + dim.height` and set it as the text property of a `JLabel` or a `JTextField` (or wherever else).  This is great for static display, but problematic for editability as you will need to manually parse the result to determine the validity of the value.  You might be able to make this easier by using `JFormattedTextField`, but's not really designed for editing multiple values...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the toString() method of the object itself you can just simply use the width and height to display them in whatever format you'd like:

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(10,20);
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
tf.setText(d.getWidth() + "x" + d.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the toString() [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html)